# how will i enabled button when two textbox is equal

Tags: javascript, ajax

i tried this codes but it seems not working. my problem is how will i enabled the button when the two textbox is equal the value?  the selected textbox is automatic will change depend on the quanity of item selected in multiple select.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>    
<script>
             function getCount(){
                 var comboBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("#tags");
                 var selected = [];
                 for(var i=0,len=comboBoxes.length;i<len;i++){
                        var combo = comboBoxes[i];
                        var options = combo.children;
                        for(var j=0,length=options.length;j<length;j++){
                             var option = options[j];
                             if(option.selected){
                               selected.push(option.text);
                             }
                        }
                 }
                         $('#selected').val(selected.length);;

             }  

</script>
<script>
function disableSubmit(){
  var firstValue = $("#quantitytotransfer").val();
  var secondValue = $("#selected").val();
  if ((firstValue == secondValue)) {
    $("#submit").attr("disabled", false);
  }else{
    $("#submit").attr("disabled", true);
  }  
}

$("#selected").on("keyup", disableSubmit);
$("#quantitytotransfer").on("keyup", disableSubmit);

</script>
<input name="imei" placeholder="quantity" id="quantitytotransfer"> 
<input name="numberselected" readonly id="selected"> 

<select id="tags" onchange="getCount()"multiple style="width: 200px;">
    <option value="aaa">aaa</option>
    <option value="bbb">bbb</option>
    <option value="ccc">ccc</option>
</select>
  <button id="submit" id="submit" disabled type="button">Get Values</button>

<script>

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy here is the code

```
<input name="imei" placeholder="quantity" id="quantitytotransfer">
<input name="numberselected" readonly id="selected">

<select id="tags" multiple style="width: 200px;">
  <option value="aaa">aaa</option>
  <option value="bbb">bbb</option>
  <option value="ccc">ccc</option>
</select>
<button id="submit" disabled type="button">Get Values</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>

$(function() {
  $("#tags").on("change", function(e) {//Whenever tags are changed it will be called 
    $('#selected').val($(this).find('option').filter(":selected").length);//this will set the count or length of selected length
    $("#submit").prop("disabled", !$("#quantitytotransfer").val() || !$("#selected").val() || ($("#quantitytotransfer").val() != $("#selected").val()));//this will disable or enable depending on equal value
  });

  var delay = (function() {// a delay function
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms){
      clearTimeout (timer);
      timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
  })();

  $('#quantitytotransfer, #selected').keyup(function() {//both text box are binded to event
    delay(function() {
      $("#submit").prop("disabled", !$("#quantitytotransfer").val() || !$("#selected").val() || ($("#quantitytotransfer").val() != $("#selected").val()));//this will disable or enable depending on equal value
    }, 1000 );//a 1 second delay used you can change to more less
  });  
});
```

Comment: its not working you enabled the button when its have a value, my problem is how will i enabled the button when the two textbox is equal

Comment: you make it disable when the two value is equal and enabled it when its not equal its not what i need :(

Comment: @CarlosJhonmanlulu sorry for my mistakes there was some logical problem but I have updated my answer this is working now you can check now

Answer (score 0):

You can compare value entered in `input` tag and selected from `select` tag in the following way:

Here how does it work:

- Listen to input on `input`.
- Listen to change on `select` tag.
- When user enter a value in `input`, run logic enable button.
- When user select a value in `select`, run logic enable button.
- Logic enable button, compare value entered and selected from `input` and `select` tag. If both values match, button is enabled otherwise is disabled.
- When a value change on `select` tag, show value in read-only `input` tag/

```js
 (function() {
   var elmQuantity = $('#quantitytotransfer'),
     elmTags = $('#tags'),
     elmSubmit = $('#submit'),
     elmSelected = $('#selected'),
     findTagsSelected = function() {
       return elmTags.find(':selected').text();
     },
     enableBtn = function() {
       if (elmQuantity.val() === findTagsSelected()) {
         elmSubmit.prop('disabled', false)
       } else {
         elmSubmit.prop('disabled', true)
       }
     };
   elmQuantity.on('input', function() {
       enableBtn();
     }),
     elmTags.change(function(value) {
       enableBtn();
       elmSelected.val(findTagsSelected());
     });
 })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="imei" placeholder="quantity" id="quantitytotransfer">
<input name="numberselected" readonly id="selected">
<select id="tags" multiple style="width: 200px;">
  <option value="aaa">aaa</option>
  <option value="bbb">bbb</option>
  <option value="ccc">ccc</option>
</select>
<button id="submit" id="submit" disabled type="button">Get Values</button>
```

Comment: @CarlosJhonmanlulu ok I have edited my question if you need further help please let me know. I hope it help.

Comment: thx bro i also need this portion in my program however its not applicable in my problem right now btw thankyou ::)

Comment: @CarlosJhonmanlulu try if this helps, if it is ok now I will update my answer https://jsfiddle.net/9vm3a0kx/ please let me know thanks